# How to deal with "none" values when inserting into SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

Some rows in my data set are like this: where None is suppose to be integer.

```
Boston (2017)   Documentary Jon Dunham  5-Dec-17    100 5   None    63  None
```

When I insert this line into Postgres, where the type of column of None is INTEGER, I got this error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "None"
```

I store the original data in a csv file, it's a really big dataset(around 2000) how should I deal with the None value?

Comment: Use `NULL` for a missing value.

Comment: To add to the above, you could also use a placeholder integer value, e.g. `-1`, assuming you never expect to have any real data which is negative.

Comment: What query do you use for an insert?

Comment: please show db schema and your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No value, or unknown in postgres is `NULL`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

> A null input is treated as the logical value “unknown”

if you sotre original data in csv format, then use `unquoted empty string` for importing csv to postgres, but from your sample it looks that you have tsc (tabs in place of commas) and thus you should use `\N` for `null`s.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> NULL
>
> Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N
>   (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV
>   format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases
>   where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This
>   option is not allowed when using binary format.

also from quote above you can explicitely specify `NULL` representation in your csv, eg:

```
t=# create table n(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy n from stdin delimiter '|' null 'None';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> 1|a
>> None|b
>> 2| None
>> None|None
>> \.
COPY 4
t=# select * from n;
 i |   t
---+-------
 1 | a
   | b
 2 |  None
   |
(4 rows)
```

I deliberately made a "typo" with `i=2`, providing `" None"`, instead of `"None"` - if you decide to use your null identifier you have to insure it does sright after delimiter, eg if you use tab (as I assume from your sample), it should be tab `chr(9)`, not two or four spaces, otherwise `"  None"` will be treated as string value, not as `NULL`...